# What's the proper way to store a long string (like a news article) in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, string

I'm working on Layer 2 so gas/efficiency aren't primary concerns, assuming the function can be executed by the EVM

Comment: Hmmmm... how about a... `string`?

Comment: I would zip the article first, but that's typically something you'd do off-chain (i.e., before sending it to the contract). Note that from a certain size, the gas required will exceed the network's block-gas-limit. So compressing your data sounds like the correct thing to do. And of course, even with that, you'd be limited at a certain point, so you'd need to write a function which concatenates, and then pass your data in chunks (i.e., execute the "data upload" in several transactions).

Answer (score 1):

Saving long strings could be very expensive operation in smart contracts. I see 2 solutions and they both require offchain actions:

1. Save each article in [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) and then save the returned hash into blockchain.
2. Save each article in database and then save the record ID into blockchain.